# Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task freezes

Tags: gruntjs

Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task freezes when I run it in command line.

My task configuration is as follows:

```
htmlmin: { // Task
  dist: { // Target
    options: { // Target options
      removeComments: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeRedundantAttributes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= cwdPath %>',
      src: ['**/*.html', '!index-requirejs.html', '!online/**/*.html', '!onlinetradingmanagement/*.html'],
      dest: '<%= destPath %>min/'
    }]
  }
}
```

Files are properly minified and generated as per the config, but from command line the execution of that task seems not to complete itself.

I want to integrate this into Jenkins-CI, so cannot afford on the task to freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason behind this problem as it was occurring to some other people too suddenly out of nowhere.

Reference from the issue that I raised a few days back:
[grunt-contrib-htmlmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin/issues/116)

This issue might arise if you have invalid HTML.

Try running `grunt htmlmin:dist --verbose`

Check the file for syntax errors and see if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to erase destination directory.
In my case, grunt couldn't overwrote minified files.